# How to determine level of evidence required in information-rich world

Tags: discussion

With such a high volume of information in our daily lives,  what are useful principles or heuristics for determining how much, or which kinds of, investigation are required for making an evaluation of a given claim?

I want to learn about **how to decide how justified** we should be making our beliefs about claims. The question stems from the problem that I don't have the resources to evaluate all the claims made to me with the most rigorous methods available. Although I would agree that principles like *the burden of proof* and *provisionalism* make this problem easier, we still need to decide if we spend five minutes or the rest of our lives working on investigating certain claims. I'm also fine saying *I don't know*, but I may also be okay saying *X is caused by Y, at least to the extend that [cited experts] can agree*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another aspect on top of the [existing answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3143/revisions) is to consider the cost of being wrong.

If you tell me adding more salt to a recipe will improve the taste, and you are wrong, I will have one substandard meal, and I will know better next time. I am willing to provisionally accept your advice, without even checking if you are an expert or have done randomised, controlled, double-blinded trials on the recipe.

If you tell me that homeopathic vaccines work against malaria when travelling, I could get horribly sick and die. I need additional evidence, and it is worth further investigation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad question. How justified should your belief in a claim be? Your belief should be in proportion to the evidence. Here are some heuristics for evaluating the evidence given certain types of claims.

For breaking news, I find *On the Media*'s "[Breaking News Consumer Handbook](http://www.onthemedia.org/story/breaking-news-consumers-handbook-pdf/)" useful.

For fact-based claims (did X happen?, did X say Y?, etc.), following the standards of good journalism will help lead you to the correct answer, or at least avoid incorrect answers. [NPR's ethics handbook](http://ethics.npr.org/category/a1-accuracy/) gives a set of tactics. Here are just a few:

- seek diverse perspectives
- double-check numbers and the way they're portrayed
- be skeptical of images; start with the presumption that they are not authentic
- identify sources for each fact you are relying on

For more nuanced claims that involve scientific uncertainty (e.g. does X cause Y?), this is a difficult task to do right. You have to familiarize yourself with the large body of research on a topic. [Give more weight to more rigorous methods and complete reviews](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2528/25668). Follow the evidence, and be willing to accept uncertainty in your conclusion. As in all exercises of skepticism, even when think you've arrived at a well supported conclusion, you need to be open to change if presented with new evidence.

Be on guard against pseudoscience. [TEDx/TED distributed a letter](http://tedx.tumblr.com/post/37405280671/a-letter-to-the-tedx-community-on-tedx-and-bad) to TEDx organizers with heuristics to help them identify pseudoscience. Here are a few:

- A mark of good science: It makes claims that can be tested and verified
- A mark of bad science: Is not based on experiments that can be reproduced by others
- Red flag behaviour: Provides data that takes the form of anecdotes, testimonials and/or studies of only one person

Comment: I agree, the question is very broad! I strongly agree with the advice you give in your answer, but my question was not 'how do we know' what we believe.