# Is the International Journal of Vaccine Theory, Practice, and Research a genuine peer review journal

Tags: discussion

Is the International Journal of Vaccine Theory, Practice, and Research considers to be a peer review journal for the purposes of use and citation on this website.

At link to it can be found here

[Website link](https://ijvtpr.com/index.php/IJVTPR)

Comment: I'd say [probably not](https://www.quora.com/Is-The-International-Journal-of-Vaccine-Theory-Practice-and-Research-a-serious-science-based-publication-or-a-mouthpiece-for-anti-vaxxers). If I saw an answer that uses eg [this](https://ijvtpr.com/index.php/IJVTPR/article/view/52) as their primary source, I'd definitely downvote. If we look at eg [this](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/may-i-cite-a-single-article) ordering of quality sources, it doesn't go above "Random web-sites".

Comment: I think not. See this article at retraction watch: https://retractionwatch.com/2021/08/11/authors-blame-a-ghoul-for-retraction-of-paper-claiming-vaccines-lead-to-health-and-behavioral-issues/

Also David Gorski has written about the same retraction, and he referred to the journal as a "bottom-feeding (albeit ostensibly “peer-reviewed”) journal" here: https://www.respectfulinsolence.com/2021/07/26/james-lyons-weiler-whines-about-his-vaxxed-unvaxxed-study-retraction/

Comment: Some good answers here also: https://www.quora.com/Is-The-International-Journal-of-Vaccine-Theory-Practice-and-Research-a-serious-science-based-publication-or-a-mouthpiece-for-anti-vaxxers

Comment: Maybe add some of this as an answer, not a comment?